# Circular buttons issue - Bootstrap 3.1.1

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, button

I'm currently working on a page that uses bootstrap 3.1.1. Here's the issue that I'm experiencing: Whenever the page loads, it shows the correct color(font and background) but not the "circular" button that I'm expecting, when I hover to it, it will now show the button that I'm expecting, circular with the correct colors. To make it short, it only turns circular when i hover to it.

here's my CSS code:

```
.btn-circle{
background-color:#e9543f; 
color:#fff; width:90px; 
height:90px;
padding: 0px; 
border-radius: 50%;}

.btn-circle:hover{ 
background-color:#e9543f; 
color:#fff; width:90px; 
height:90px;
padding: 0px; 
border-radius: 50%;}
```

Comment: Just disregard the two "\" on the code, I don't have them in my css, might be a misclick when typing this post.

Comment: send the link which u saw and tried

Comment: I'm suspecting that the CSS class is overridden somewhere. Could you post more information or make a fiddle?

Comment: Sounds like it could a specificity issue. Does it work if you add `!important` to the `border-radius: 50%` in `.btn-circle`? E.g. `border-radius: 50% !important;`

Comment: Are you including your own CSS before or after Bootstrap's? If you're doing it before Bootstrap's CSS, it's probably being overridden by their `.btn` styling, assuming your element also uses that class.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, the internet here went down, sorry for the late reply. It was solved by adding "!important" thanks!